# prevent specific character input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field like below

```
<input type='text' class='keywordInput' value='' />
```

I want to restrict specific special characters to be input. I have written following code snippet but it does not work for the first time restricted character is input.

```
$(".keywordInput").on("keypress", function (e) {
  var pattern = /[&/\\#,+(\);@$<>?^~%":\\*?<>|[\]'\{\}]/g;
  if (pattern.test(e.currentTarget.value)) {
    return false
  }
});
```

I have created jsfiddle demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xnwbg4e2/). you can try pressing `>` it will input this character once and will not allow to write any character (even alphanumeric) afterwards.My Goal is to prevent inputing `>` on the first time also & I want to achieve it using jquery

Comment: Note: `keypress` has been deprecated so may stop working in any future browser.  See [MDN keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event)

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pattern = /[&/\\#,+(\);@$<>?^~%":\\*?<>|[\]'\{\}]/g;

const onKeydown = event => {
  const match = event.key.match(pattern)
  if (match !== null) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
}

document.querySelector('.keywordInput').addEventListener('keydown', onKeydown)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<input type='text' class='keywordInput' value='' />
```

Comment: the issue with this code is that if I try to input the character in the middle of string then cursor auto jumps to the end of string

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  See [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)